# ¿Cómo agrego saltos de linea automáticos en un input text de HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, text

tengo un formulario el cual envía texto mediante un input text, lo que yo quiero hacer es que al escribir X cantidad de caracteres se me haga un salto de linea automático en el texto.

```
<form action="">

<input type="text">

<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

¿Hay alguna propiedad de html o algun codigo funcional en javascript para cumplir con esto? llevo buscando hace horas y no encuentro nada.

Comment: Estás buscando [<textarea>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) ?

Answer (score 1):

No sé si haya alguna propiedad que te permita hacer eso con un input tipo text, pero hice una función que hace lo que tú estás buscando

https://jsfiddle.net/sywptmbk/

Declaro una variable stringLength y un contador, cada que el ciclo for se corre, revisa si el contador es igual a stringLength, que es la variable que le indica que debe hacer un salto de línea, así que cada que el contador es igual a la variable, le agrega un '\n' a el string, que indica un salto de línea, y al final imprimo la variable texto, que es una variable que inicializo con el valor que está en el input. No sé si sea la mejor solución, pero es la forma en la que yo lo hice, espero te haya servido